# como puedo usalor HttpPostedFileBase en asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, httppostedfilebase

HttpPostedFileBase

I want to solve this problem to store the image to the database. I still don't run the project, if I have errors or an easier way to do it

```
 public IActionResult Create(Productos prod [Bind("codigoFoto"] Productos productos, HttpPostedFileBase FotoProducto) 
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(JObject.FromObject(prod));
            using (var _context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var Categoria = _context.Categorias.Where(i => i.IsActive && i.Id == prod.Categoria.Id).FirstOrDefault(); 
                if (prod != null)
                {
                    if (FotoProducto != null && FotoProducto.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] imageData = null;

                        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(FotoProducto.InputStream))
                        {
                            imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(FotoProducto.ContentLength);
                        }
                        //setear la imagen a la entidad que se creara
                        productos.Foto = imageData;
                    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't written in English

Comment: Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).  Please write posts (**including titles**) in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much this served me

```
Create(Productos prod [Bind("codigoFoto"] Productos productos, IFormFile FotoProducto)
```

but I also had to make a change to this code

```
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(FotoProducto.InputStream))

var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                    var file = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

                    file = Path.Combine(file, FotoProducto.FileName);


                    using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
```

Answer (score 0):

In **.Net Core** you must use `IFormFile` instead of `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Replace

```cs
Create(Productos prod [Bind("codigoFoto"] Productos productos, HttpPostedFileBase FotoProducto)
```

to

```
Create(Productos prod [Bind("codigoFoto"] Productos productos, IFormFile FotoProducto)
```

this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1) maybe helpful for you